# Ruby repeat thread

Tags: ruby, multithreading

So I've got a reporter method running in a separate thread, it looks a little like this

```
def report
  @reporters.each do |reporter|
    Thread.new{ reporter.report }
  end
end
```

The intention is that the reporter objects don't interfere with the performance of my main code loop. However this does create a lot of new threads, which seems to be taking up a lot of resources.

I'd like to instead collect those new threads and re-run them when the report method is called. Or send a single thread the report method on the reporter objects each time it's called.

Is there a way I can call methods in a separate thread after initialising it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although I side with @AlexeyShein that a tested library is the better option, allow me to raise a few thoughts/issues as well as offer a basic thread-pool demo.

The code I offer is similar to what I wrote for the [Iodine](https://github.com/boazsegev/iodine) project, although simpler and a bit less optimized.

1. **Tasks in your thread pool might NOT complete**:

   When the hosting OS/server shuts your application down, it might not wait for all your tasks to complete.

   The hosting OS/server will usually wait a short while (on Heroku it could be up to 30 seconds) before deciding your application had enough time and forcefully kills the process.

   This is normal and expected behavior.
2. **Tasks are NOT persistent**:

   Whenever your application restarts, the task queue will be a fresh and clean queue.

   To resolve this issue, it is common to do two things: 1. Save the tasks in a database / module; and 2. run the background task manager in a different process (to avoid race conditions when scaling the application).

If you **don't** mind having incomplete tasks reinitiated after shutdown, here's a relatively simple thread-pool solution.

The following test code should show you how even small tasks might cause the `rundown` to linger after exit was called. If your application will linger for long enough, it could be forcefully shut down by your host.

```
class ThreadPool
    def initialize number_of_threads
        @queue = Queue.new
        @stop = false
        @threads = []
        number_of_threads.times do
            @threads << Thread.new { work until @stop }
        end
        Kernel.at_exit { rundown }
    end

    def run &block
        return false unless block
        @queue << block
        block
    end

    protected

    def work
        begin
            @queue.pop.call
        rescue => e
            warn "A background task failed with #{e.message}"
        end
    end

    def rundown
        sleep 0.1 until @queue.empty?
        stop
        join
        work until @queue.empty?
    end

    # will wait for all threads to finish
    # if stop isn't called, this will hang forever!
    def join
        @threads.each {|t| t.join rescue true }
    end

    # will stop the thread pool and let the threads exit normally
    def stop
        @stop = true
        (@threads.count * 2).times {  run { nil } }
    end
end



BK = ThreadPool.new 12
100.times {|i| BK.run {sleep 0.2; puts i.to_s} }

exit
```

Comment: Oops, I had a slight typo at the `stop` method, as I still called the `run` method using it's older name (`defer`). It's fixed now, so no errors should show up after the ThreadPool finishes to rundown.

Answer (score 1):

That design pattern is called *thread pool*. There is plenty of information on the internet regarding Ruby implementation of thread pool.

Answer (score 0):

Multithreading can be tricky, so I think the best option in your case would be to use some battle-tested library like [`sidekiq`](http://sidekiq.org/) that would take all heavy-lifting on itself.